# Stepping through the Roslyn C# compiler

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've built the Roslyn source as [described here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/contributing/Building,%20Debugging,%20and%20Testing%20on%20Windows.md).

I'd like to add a breakpoint in the C# compiler and step through the compliation of this simple program:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = 1 + 2;

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Where should I set a breakpoint? It should be early in the compilation process as I'd like to step through parsing and even lexing.

If I set CompilerExtension as the startup project and hit F5 (Start Debugging), a copy of Visual Studio is launched running the newly built compiler. I'd like to avoid having to launch a new instance of Visual Studio each time I'd like to step through the compiler. What's a good way to setup a small program which invokes the compiler code on the above source directly?

Comment: You could add a new project to the Roslyn solution, add references to the correct Microsoft.CodeAnalysis projects and then call `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText()` and `Compilation.Emit()`. Then you could step through either the parsing or emitting code you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks Josh! I've added an answer that demonstrates `ParseText`.  @JoshVarty

Comment: I've written a blog article somewhat based on what @JoshVarty suggests here and in one of his blog articles. This may be of interest for anyone wanting to play around with Roslyn internals. https://renniestechblog.com/information/33-modifying-roslyn-step-1-initial-test

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach as suggested by Josh in a comment above.

- Add a new "Console Application" project to the Roslyn solution.
- Add these two references to the project:

[image]

A simple program to test the parser:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace TestCompiler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program_text = @"

                using System;

                namespace ConsoleApplication2
                {
                    class Program
                    {
                        static void Main(string[] args) 
                        { var result = 2 + 3; Console.WriteLine(result); }
                    }
                }
            ";

            var result = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(program_text);
        }
    }
}
```

- Add a breakpoint to the line that calls `ParseText`.
- "Start Debugging" and step into that line to delve into the parser.

A simple program to test the compiler via `Emit`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace TestCompiler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program_text = @"

                using System;

                namespace ConsoleApplication2
                {
                    class Program
                    {
                        static void Main(string[] args) 
                        { var result = 2 + 3; Console.WriteLine(result); }
                    }
                }
            ";

            var syntax_tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(program_text);

            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"),
                new[] { syntax_tree },
                new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll") });

            var emit_result = compilation.Emit(new MemoryStream());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the current version of Roslyn and for Visual Studio 2017 you also need to add a reference to the NuGet package for System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.4.2. Until I determined that (and it took me a long time) I was getting "The application is in break mode", and was unable to do anything at all. This may be due to a bug in Visual Studio https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/104485/the-application-is-in-break-mode-1.html What finally provided the clue to the real problem was when I double-clicked on the generated .exe file - then I got an error in the console window.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a simple program that invokes the compiler, just consider using csc as your startup project. You can specify the arguments to pass (like source files) from the debug settings on the project.

Comment: Thanks Jason! I'm currently exploring the approach mentioned by Josh in a comment above. It seems to be working well so far. I've added an answer that describes that approach.

Comment: This seems like logical way to test the Roslyn compiler under the Visual Studio debugger. But there are so many possible arguments for csc.exe. Do you have a link or a suggestion about which arguments are needed and which additional arguments may be a good idea to use as well?